# Why not upload this block? XML and Magento

Tags: xml, magento

I have this code **XML:**

```
 <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                    <label>Page Footer</label>
                    <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
                </block>
                <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" after="*" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>

                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Quick Links</title></action>
                </block>
  /*---- here is my block---*/
                 <block type="cms/block" name="Footer Links">
                     <action method="footer_links3"><block_id>name-of-static-block</block_id></action>
                 </block>
   /*---- here is my block---*/
                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links2" as="footer_links2" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>Account</title></action>
                </block>

                <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links3" as="footer_links3" template="page/template/links.phtml">
                    <action method="setTitle"><title>ss</title></action>
                </block>
                <!-- This static block can be created and populated in admin. The footer_links cms block can be used as a starting point. -->
                <block type="cms/block" name="footer_social_links">
                    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_social_links</block_id></action>
                </block>
            </block>
```

I added this code in **page.xml**

From **CMS-static block** section we have created the next block with the following atributes:

1. Block Title = Footer Links
2. Identifier = footer_links3
3. Store View = All store views

**Can you please tell me what is wrong and why nothing is printed on site?**

**EDIT:**

footer.phtml code

```
<div class="footer-container">
    <div class="footer">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_footer_links') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
        <address class="copyright"><?php echo $this->getCopyright() ?></address>
    </div>
</div>
```

xml code:

```
 <block type="cms/block" name="my_footer_links">
                       <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links3</block_id></action>
                </block>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="Footer Links">
   <action method="footer_links3"><block_id>name-of-static-block</block_id></action>
</block>
```

with:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="my_footer_links">
   <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links3</block_id></action>
</block>
```

You have used **footer_links3** in action method, which is wrong.

After that, you will need to call it from footer.phtml file using $this->getChildHtml method.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('my_footer_links') ?>
```

After checking please let me know result.

Comment: nothing has changed ... still do not see the clock on the site

Comment: Please see my edited reply and let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: I put your code now and nothing's happening ... I do not understand what you mean

Comment: In your edited question, you have still not changed code in xml file.
Please use:

<block type="cms/block" name="my_footer_links">
   <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links3</block_id></action>
</block>

in xml file instead of your code.